# How do I click on links that are contained in a div container fluid using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-testing

I'm writing a piece of python code to test whether users are able to click on dynamic tabs.

I'm using `find_elements_by_xpath()` to search for attributes of the tab. Now, this is a dynamic set of tabs, so they will never be viewable in the page source. But they do exist when I click on inspect element.

I'm using something like this to identify the tabs:

```
elem = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@role,'tab')]")
for i in elem:
    print(i.text)
```

I tried the get_attribute feature but that did not work. Is there any way I can use python selenium to click on a dynamic tab (that does not appear on page source)?

Answer (score 0):

You can [wait some time](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) until required element present in `DOM` and clickable:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait(self.browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@role, "tab")]'))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks Andersson. This really helps. Just one thing though - I have multiple tabs and this only helps me select the first one. Is there a way I can extend this to multiple tabs? The documentation does not suggest that there is some way, for e.g. elements_to_be_clickable or something like that?

Comment: Usually you might need to click just one link, so you might use more specific `XPath` to match just required link or if you want to get, for example, link text of each element you can replace `EC.element_to_be_clickable` with `EC.presence_of_all_elements_located`